# Compiled and target SDK version higher than device SDK version

Tags: android

My compiled and target sdk version is 26, but the phone I'm debugging on is running 24.

From what I understand, the compiled sdk version is just the version of the sdk that the compiler actually uses during compilation, but will my device just ignore the features of the later version?

Comment: Yes. Your device doesn't have the features introduced after API 24. So in that device those features won't work.

Comment: if you are using support librarys for certain things then you will be fine,but the features added later 24 will not be available in the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile sdk is just used for compilation. It has no effect on runtime behaviour since it's not packaged inside your app.

Any features which are exclusive to API later than 24 will not work but you will get an error during compilation/development if you used them without certain checks depending on what minSdk you specify.
Exception is support libraries which are packaged inside the app.